# get items in listboxitem

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have an xaml code about listbox object:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="FirstListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="50,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,60,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>                                
                            </StackPanel>                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

i was get my listboxitem by the code :

```
ListBoxItem item = this.list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(2) as ListBoxItem;
```

but i don't know how to get all items in this listbox item (including textblock and checkbox option).

please help me. thanks all.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to have your checkbox bound to a property of your item data model, so for example, you may have...

```
public string LineOne { get; set; }
public string LineTwo { get; set; }
public bool MyBooleanValue { get; set; }
```

and then

```
<ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="FirstListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="50,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,60,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    <CheckBox Checked="{Binding MyBoolValue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                </Grid>                                
            </StackPanel>                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then you can pull back the DataContext for the item you are currently looking at (on a tap method or similar), or when you parse through your "Items" collection, all the checkbox states will be in the child objects for you already.